# Web Audio - cancelScheduledValues - keep current value?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Using Webaudio - When calling cancelScheduledValues() in the middle of a transition from one value value to another - the value reverts back to its starting point.

Is there a way to cancel the transition but keep the value at the point it managed to get to?

Here is where the filter envelope is triggered:

```
_this.filter1.frequency.cancelScheduledValues(startTime);
_this.filter1.frequency.setValueAtTime(cutoffStart, startTime);
_this.filter1.frequency.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(cutoffEnd, startTime + _this.filterDecayTime);
```

Comment: Do you have sample code?  It's not supposed to do this, but future scheduling will start from the previous value.  There's a bug to change this in the spec, but it's not done yet.

Comment: Ok, this may have been my mistake here. I think my issue more relates to some odd behavior from setTargetAtTime and what happens afterwards - but I should probably open another question for that one.

Comment: Ah.  setTargetAtTime is a bit different.

Comment: An example would be really great.  Can't tell what's happening if we don't know what's in the timeline when you call `cancelScheduledValues`.

Comment: For the record, https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-cancelAndHoldAtTime-AudioParam-double-cancelTime is part of the spec now. I doubt anyone has this implemented yet.